# Update object based on dictionary

Tags: c#

stack
I have a class Team which contains a list of Players. I create a Team object, add some Players to it. By default the Players in Team have playerPoints value of 0.

Then I receive a dictionary which has player `id` playerPoints combination. I need to lookup the dictionary `myDict` with Team object on `id` and update Team object with `playerPoints`. how do I do that?

```
public class Player

{

    public int id { get; set; }

    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public int playerPoints{ get; set; }



    public Player(int id, string firstName)

    {

        this.id = id;

        this.firstName = firstName;

        this.playerPoints = 0;

    }

}



public class Team

{

    public string TeamName { get; set; }

    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }



    public Team(string teamName)

    {

        this.TeamName = teamName;

        Players = new List<Player>();

    }



    public void AddPlayer(Player p)

    {

        Players.Add(p);

    }

}



        var playerList = new List<Player>()

        {

            new Player(1,"Player1"),

            new Player(2,"Player2"),

        };



        var tm = new Team("Team1");

        foreach (Player p in playerList)

        {

            tm.AddPlayer(p);

        }





        var myDict = new Dictionary<int, int>

        {

            { 1, 65 },

            { 2, 33 }

        };
```

Comment: Loop through your dictionary, get the player from your `Players`-list within `Team` that matches the current id and set its `playerPoints`-property.

Answer (score 1):

First loop your dictionary. Then for every item search for the `Player` with the current id and set its `playerPoints`-property:

```
foreach(var kv in myDict)
{
    var player = theTeam.Players.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == kv.Key);
    if(player != null)
        player.playerPoints = kv.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expand `Team` class with method `public void AddPlayersPoints(Dictionary<int, int> playersPoints)`
so you can call it like this: `tm.AddPlayersPoints(myDict);`.

Modify `Team` class property `public List<Player> Players { get; set; }` to be dictionary instead of list `public Dictionary<int, Player> Players { get; set; }`.
Modify `AddPlayer` to add to dictionary instead like `Players.Add(p.id, p);`
This is the essence really, to use Dictionary instead of list, so you don't have to iterate through List for every item in `myDict`. Other modifications are all related to single responsibility principle.

Player class should have its own method `AddPoints`.
All this to respect responsibility of all classes involved.
At the end

```
public void AddPlayersPoints(Dictionary<int, int> playersPoints) 
{
    foreach(var playerPoints in playersPoints) 
    {
        if (Players.ContainsKey(playerPoints.Key)) 
        {
            Players[playerPoint.Key].AddPoints(playerPoints.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

Player method

```
public void AddPoints(int points) 
{
    playerPoints += points;  // No check. Points could be negative, but that depends on your logic.
}
```